# signature function of Weyl group element in LieArt

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, computer-algebra-systems

I am currently using LieArt Mathematica package for some calculations in Lie algebra, I am wondering if there is a way to know what is the signature of a Weyl group element, it seems the package can be used to generate all Weyl orbits, but it can not tell you directly the corresponding signature of the group element.